# Getting Warning: " 'newdata' had 5 rows but variables found have 750 rows" even though column names are the same

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have a dataset called `PimaDiabetes`. And the dataset can be [pulled from here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database?datasetId=228&sortBy=voteCount&select=diabetes.csv).

```
PimaDiabetes <- read.csv("PimaDiabetes.csv")
```

From which I derived a logistic model:

```
chosen_glm = glm(PimaDiabetes$Outcome ~ PimaDiabetes$Pregnancies+PimaDiabetes$Glucose
+PimaDiabetes$SkinThickness+PimaDiabetes$BMI
+PimaDiabetes$DiabetesPedigree, data = PimaDiabetes)
```

However, when ever I try to run it against a new dataset called ToPredict:

| Pregnancies | Glucose | BloodPressure | SkinThickness | Insulin | BMI | DiabetesPedigree | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 136 | 70 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 31.2 | 22 |
| 1 | 121 | 78 | 39 | 74 | 20 | 39 | 28 |
| 3 | 108 | 62 | 24 | 0 | 20 | 26 | 25 |
| 0 | 181 | 88 | 44 | 510 | 20 | 43.3 | 26 |
| 8 | 154 | 78 | 32 | 0 | 20 | 32.4 | 45 |

I get the following error:

```
>predict(chosen_glm,ToPredict,type="response")

Warning message:
'newdata' had 5 rows but variables found have 750 rows
```

And I'm not sure what's wrong.

The colnames

```
colnames(PimaDiabetes)
"Pregnancies"      "Glucose"          "BloodPressure"    "SkinThickness"    "Insulin"          "BMI"              "DiabetesPedigree" "Age"             
[9] "Outcome"
```

Are the same

```
colnames(ToPredict)
[1] "Pregnancies"      "Glucose"          "BloodPressure"    "SkinThickness"    "Insulin"          "BMI"              "DiabetesPedigree" "Age"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PimaDiabetes = read.csv("diabetes.csv")
chosen_glm = glm(
  Outcome ~ Pregnancies + Glucose + SkinThickness + BMI + DiabetesPedigreeFunction,
  data = PimaDiabetes
)

ToPredict = PimaDiabetes[sample(nrow(PimaDiabetes),5),]

predict(chosen_glm,ToPredict,type="response")
```